# Trying to get property 'user_id' of non-object when db record is created

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.8

I am having a very weird experience with my code today. I could swear all worked well until today.

Here's the thing, I have a one to one relationship between `User` and `BankAccount` model like this

```
public function bankAccount()
{
    return $this->hasOne(BankAccount::class, 'user_id');
}
```

When a user account is created initially, there is no record in the `bank_accounts` table for the user. A user can then create the bank account record with this method

```
public function update(Request $request, User  $user)
{
    // create record if user does not have a bankAccount
    if (!$user->bankAccount) {

        $user->bankAccount()->create($request->all());
    } else {

        $user->bankAccount()->update($request->all());
    }

    return new BankAccountResource($user->bankAccount);
}
```

And the `BankAccountResource`

```
public function toArray($request)
{
    return [
        'user_id'       => $this->user_id,
        'bank_name'     => $this->bank_name,
        'bvn'           => $this->bvn,
        'account_no'    => $this->account_no
    ];
}
```

The problem I am experiencing is that when the user creates the bank account record the first time with `$user->bankAccount()->create($request->all());` I get the following error exception

> "message": "Trying to get property 'user_id' of non-object"
>   But in the db, the record is actually created so I wonder why the error is thrown.

For update `$user->bankAccount()->update($request->all());`, I get the proper response returned which looks like this

```
{
    "user_id": 13,
    "bank_name": "bank name",
    "account": 1324354611
}
```

How can I fix this behavior?

Comment: I don't see any code here that tries to access a user_id property? The error should give you a file and line number of the offending code.

Comment: @Jonnix I added a description of the `BankAccountResource` that has the `user_id`. Note the relationship I mentioned earlier and the fact that the issue happens only when a record is created for the first time but it doesn't occur when an update is made to the record.

Comment: try to store the create method to a variable and send the variable as the response. I mean `$account = $user->bankAccount()->create($request->all()); return new BankAccountResource($account );` try like this.

Comment: @zahidhasanemon tried doing it as suggested but it reversed the experience. So `create` would return right response but `update` throws error

Comment: what error you are getting now?

Answer (score 0):

I think that the correc is create $user, after created you can us your user and your relationship to create bankAccount:

```
$user = User::create($request->all());
$userBank = $user->bankAccount()->create($request->all());
```

You need to have the $user before, to use it.